# mkdir() warning generated even though script was successful

Tags: php, fwrite, mkdir

I'm creating a content management system whereby the user can create categories and sections dynamically through an interface.  It's PHP and MySQL driven - when the user clicks the form to submit the user info to the database, it dynamically creates the directory (if it doesn't already exist) and an index file (if it doesn't already exist.)  In addition, the user can specify a specific file corresponding to the section being created that is also created at the same time.

What I've been getting is everything I need: the directory, the index file and the section file but I've also been getting a mkdir() warning error.  The warning says "Warning: mkdir() [function.mkdir]: File exists in.." and gives the line that the mkdir function appears on.  I'm using the file_exists() function to make sure that the directory and index file don't already exist, however, it doesn't appear to be working.  Any ideas?

My code is:

```
$dir = $category."/";

        if (file_exists($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].$dir)) {
            chdir($dir);

            $newFileName = $link_name.".php";
            $newFileHandle = fopen($newFileName, 'w+') or die("can't open file");
            $category = $_POST['category'];
            $category = strtoupper($category);
            fwrite($newFileHandle, implode("\r\n", $content));
            fwrite($newFileHandle, '"'.$category.'"'.';');
            fwrite($newFileHandle, implode("\r\n", $php_cat_content));
            fwrite($newFileHandle, '"'.$section_name.'"'.';');
            fwrite($newFileHandle, implode("\r\n", $php_sec_content));
            fclose($newFileHandle);
        }
        else {
            $dir = str_replace (" ", "", $category) ."/";
            mkdir($dir, 0777);
            chdir($dir);

            if (!file_exists("index.php")) {
            $index_fn = "index.php";
            $index_fh = fopen($index_fn, 'w+') or die("can't open file");
            $category = $_POST['category'];
            $category = strtoupper($category);
            fwrite($index_fh, implode("\r\n", $content));
            fwrite($index_fh, '"'.$category.'"'.';');
            fwrite($index_fh, implode("\r\n", $php_cat_content));
            fwrite($index_fh, '"'.$section_name.'"'.';');
            fwrite($index_fh, implode("\r\n", $php_sec_content));
            fclose($index_fh);
            }

            else {
            $newFileName = $link_name.".php";
            $newFileHandle = fopen($newFileName, 'w+') or die("can't open file");
            $category = $_POST['category'];
            $category = strtoupper($category);
            fwrite($newFileHandle, implode("\r\n", $content));
            fwrite($newFileHandle, '"'.$category.'"'.';');
            fwrite($newFileHandle, implode("\r\n", $php_cat_content));
            fwrite($newFileHandle, '"'.$section_name.'"'.';');
            fwrite($newFileHandle, implode("\r\n", $php_sec_content));
            fclose($newFileHandle);
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

A warning doesn't stop script execution. It's telling you that you're trying to create a directory that already exists. You need to use [`is_dir()`](http://php.net/is_dir) to check if the directory exists or not before you attempt to create it, then the warning will go away.

Are you sure `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].$dir` is accurate? Below that, you're creating the directory *just* using `$dir` with nothing on the front, but you're checking the directory's existence with a document root on the front of it.

The rest of your code works because the directory *does* exist, it didn't need to be created.

Comment: I replaced file_exists() with is_dir() in the appropriate spot and got the same, if not similar results.  Is that what you were thinking?  Replacing  file_exists() with is_dir()?

Comment: @jbrown574: Your files are likely being stored in a different location than you're checking in your conditional.

Answer (score 0):

`$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].$category."/"` and `str_replace (" ", "", $category) ."/"`, are you sure they are same?

Answer (score 0):

You need a slash after `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']`.

```
if ( file_exists( $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/" . $dir ) ) {
```

Should sort out any problems.

I also notice this is probably missing the `$_SERVER['DOCUEMENT_ROOT'] . "/"` all together

```
 $dir = str_replace (" ", "", $category) ."/";
 mkdir($dir, 0777);
```

should be  ( I think )

```
 $dir = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/" . str_replace (" ", "", $category) ."/";
 mkdir($dir, 0777);
```

Comment: I had a feeling that it might have something to do with the absolute path... thanks.  I'll give it a whirl.  Like I said, it works, just not well. ;-/